# HttpInterceptingHandler is not a constructor while universal rendering angularjs 6

Tags: angular, angular6, universal, server-rendering

I'm trying to setup the server side rendering of my `angular app`, I have followed the instruction from here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Every command runs successfully, but after starting node server, when I try to visit the url, It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: _angular_common_http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.ɵHttpInterceptingHandler is not a constructor
    at zoneWrappedInterceptingHandler (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:4040:23)
    at _callFactory (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:14256:20)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:14210:26)
    at initNgModule (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:14143:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:14872:9)
    at Object.createNgModuleRef (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:14861:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:17394:25)
    at /Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:9693:43
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:515:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (/Stuff/Development/Angular/angular-tuts/universal/dist/server.js:9035:33)
```

Comment: see here:https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/issues/59

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but my issue is not related to decimal, It's related to `HttpInterceptingHandler`, so that doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Update your angular dependencies

```
ng update @angular/core
```

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: By doing this, an error occurs. Invalid range: ">=2.3.1"